# How can I calculate $ \int_0^t\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi (t-s)}}\exp\left({-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4(t-s)}}\right) y\ dy\ ds $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I got the following integral 
$$
\int_0^t\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi (t-s)}}\exp\left({-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4(t-s)}}\right) y\ dy\ ds\tag{*}
$$
when I solve the heat equation using the heat kernel on the whole real line:

> $$
> u_t=u_{xx}+x, \quad u(x,0)\equiv 0.
> $$

On the other hand, it is easy to check that $$u(x,t)=xt$$ is a solution.

I'm interested in evaluating (*). But I don't see an approachable way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner integral is the expectation of a random variable with normal distribution $\mathcal N(x,2(t-s))$ hence its value is $x$. Integrating this from $s=0$ to $s=t$ yields $xt$.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: @Lost1 No clue. A fan, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the method of Duhamel.

auxiliary problem: For every fixed $s>0$, consider a homogeneous heat equation for $t>s$, with $x$ as the initial data at time $t=s$,

D.E: $u_t(x,t;s)-u_{xx}(x,t;s)=0$, $-\infty<x<\infty$, $t>s$

I.C: $u(x,s;s)=x$,  $-\infty<x<\infty$

It is know that the solution $u(x,t;s)$ of this auxiliary problem is

$u(x,t;s)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x-y,t-s)ydy$,  $-\infty<x<\infty$, $t>s$

where $K(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-x^2/(4t)}$.

Principle of Duhamel: The solution of the problem is given by

$u(x,t)=\int\limits_0^tu(x,t;s)ds$.

Thus the result follows.